# Change the name of the wp_editor tab "html/text"

Tags: wp-editor, tabs

I'm using the German version of WordPress and in wp_editor the two tabs for "visual" and "html" are named "visuell" and "text".

I would like to change the "text" tab to "html". Do you know how I can achieve that?

Here is a screenshot to show you exactly which tab I am talking about.

http://s1.directupload.net/images/130423/mtor72tu.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter `gettext_with_context` and change the name here:

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/* Plugin Name: Rename 'Text' editor to 'HTML' */
add_filter( 'gettext_with_context', 'change_editor_name_to_html', 10, 4 );

function change_editor_name_to_html( $translated, $text, $context, $domain )
{
    if ( 'default' !== $domain )
        return $translated;

    if ( 'Text' !== $text )
        return $translated;

    if ( 'Name for the Text editor tab (formerly HTML)' !== $context )
        return $translated;

    return 'HTML';
}
```

#### Result

[image]